# Python Classes: turn all inherited methods private

Tags: python, class

Class Bar inherits from Foo:

```
class Foo(object):
      def foo_meth_1(self):
          return 'foometh1'
      def foo_meth_2(self):
          return 'foometh2'
class Bar(Foo):
      def bar_meth(self):
          return 'bar_meth'
```

Is there a way of turning all methods inherited from Foo private?

```
class Bar(Foo):
      def bar_meth(self):
          return 'bar_meth'
      def __foo_meth_1(self):
          return 'foometh1'
      def __foo_meth_2(self):
          return 'foometh2'
```

Comment: You wouldn't be a very good Foo if you hid the methods of Foo.

Comment: If you wanted to do that wouldn't it be better to simple *have a `Bar` instance* as opposed to inheriting from it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: @ Joachim Sauer - Agree,it's just an example. I am trying to dig into classes and learn what can be done and what not.

Comment: Wouldn't an adapter be a better solution, than inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't have privates, only obfuscated method names. But I suppose you could iterate over the methods of the superclass when creating the instance, removing them from yourself and creating new obfuscatingly named method names for those functions. setattr and getattr could be useful if you use a function to create obfuscated names.

With that said, it's a pretty cthuhlu-oid thing to do. You mention the intent is to keep the namespace cleaner, but this is more like mixing ammonia and chlorine. If the method needs to be hidden, hide it in the superclass. The don't create instances of the superclass -- instead create a specific class that wraps the hidden methods in public ones, which you could name the same thing but strip the leading whitespace.

Assuming I understand your intent correctly, I would suggest doing something like this:

```
class BaseFoo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('No instances of BaseFoo please.')
    def _foo(self):
        return 'Foo.'
    def _bar(self):
        return 'Bar.'

class HiddenFoo(BaseFoo):
    def __init__(self): pass

class PublicFoo(BaseFoo):
    def __init__(self): pass
    foo = BaseFoo._foo
    bar = BaseFoo._bar

def try_foobar(instance):
    print 'Trying ' + instance.__class__.__name__
    try:
        print 'foo: ' + instance.foo
        print 'bar: ' + instance.bar
    except AttributeError, e:
        print e

foo_1 = HiddenFoo()
foo_2 = PublicFoo()
try_foobar(foo_1)
try_foobar(foo_2)
```

And if `PublicFoo.foo` would do something more than `BaseFoo.foo`, you would write a wrapper that does whatever is needed, and then calls foo from the superclass.

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible with Pyhtons's metaclasses. But this is quite sophisticated and I am not sure if it is worth the effort. For details have a look  [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/five-minutes.shtml)

Why would you like to do so?

Comment: It is you own local namespace, so I cannot see how you would "pollute" it. But anyways, if you change the method name to a private one, all internal method calls of your original class would need to change as well, which is not even possible with metaclass.

Comment: "it's difficult and it's a bad idea" is not a bad answer when trying to lear something. so, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use metaclasses, but `Boo` will no longer be an actual subclass of Foo, unless you want `Foo`'s methods to be both 'private' and 'public' in instances of `Bar` (you cannot selectively inherit names or `delattr` members inherited from parent classes). Here is a very contrived example:

```
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction

class TurnPrivateMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, d):
        private = {'__%s' % i:j for i,j in getmembers(bases[0]) if isfunction(j)}
        d.update(private)

        return type.__new__(cls, name, (), d)

class Foo:
    def foo_meth_1(self): return 'foometh1'
    def foo_meth_2(self): return 'foometh2'

class Bar(Foo, metaclass=TurnPrivateMetaclass):
    def bar_meth(self): return 'bar_meth'

b = Bar()
assert b.__foo_meth_1() == 'foometh1'
assert b.__foo_meth_2() == 'foometh2'
assert b.bar_meth() == 'bar_meth
```

If you wanted to get attribute access working, you could create a new `Foo` base class  in `__new__` with all renamed methods removed.

Answer (score 0):

Since `foo()` and `__foo()` are completely different methods with no link between them, Python is unable to understand what you want to do. So you have to explain to it step by step, meaning (like sapth said) to remove the old methods and add new ones.

This is an Object Oriented Design flaw and a better approach would be through delegation:

```
class Basic:
    def meth_1(self):
        return 'meth1'

    def meth_2(self):
        return 'meth2'


class Foo(Basic):
    # Nothing to do here
    pass


class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dg = Basic()

    def bar_meth(self):
        return 'bar_meth ' + self.__meth_1()

    def __meth_1(self):
        return self.dg.meth_1()

    def __meth_2(self):
        return self.dg.meth_2()
```

While `Foo` inherits the `Basic` class because he wants the public methods from him, `Bar` will only delegate the job to `Basic` because he doesn't want to integrate `Basic`'s interface into its own interface.